# How to store parent position in Android listview with two child types?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have an adapter class which contains two child layout types, I used two different view holders for two of them. while initializing the second view I am storing the last initialized first layout position(Header) to second views(Child) using setter method. It is working fine if the layout is not scrolling but if the scrool changes the parent position is getting wrong. so How can I get the header position while perform click on child .

Comment: your question is not clear, please re-word it and provide some example

Comment: Simply How to find the header position in while click on child layout

Comment: How to find section header position while click on child?

Comment: you will have to do that manually, do one more pass through your list, storing the header position for each child view into SparseBooleanArray